# Bootstrap collapse within a carousel slide - need to close it if slide item is not active

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3 carousel to turn items like this one:

```
<!-- here is an item, which could get as well class "active" -->
<div class="item">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-10 col-offset-1 text-center item-ref">
       <div class="reference">some text</div>

       <!-- collapsing item here -->
       <a href="#long-2" data-toggle="collapse" class="reference-long arr_down"></a>
       <div id="long-2" class="collapse">some collapsable text</div>

       <div class="osoba">text</div>
       <div class="firma">text</div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I need to solve problem if the *div.item* has not class *active* anymore, the eventual *class="in"* in the *div#long-2* (or eventually different number here) is turned back to *class="collapse"*.

I now, that I can probably do that in jquery, but I'm really not good in it all, could anybody help me?

Comment: A jsFiddle would be helpful.

Comment: @Schmalzy [Here you go](http://www.bootply.com/wzulcrz4Rz), but without jquery js slider because I have no idea how to add it there.
Current webpage is [here](http://demo.kybernaut.cz/dgsimona/reference/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this is what you are looking for.

1. use the built-in `slide.bs.carousel` event to find the slide that is about to be displayed.
2. Find the `div` element within that slide where the id begins with "long" and remove the `in` class.

Javascript

```
$('#quote-carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (event) {
  var item = event.relatedTarget;
  $(item).find("div[id^='long']").removeClass('in').addClass('collapse');
})
```

http://www.bootply.com/WdWLajlCIt

Comment: Works nicely in bootly but I have no clue why it's not working at [the page](http://demo.kybernaut.cz/dgsimona/reference/), [code](http://pastebin.com/PQCXWztH), do you have any idea? I've really copied the code from source...

Comment: See my update above, I don't think it was finding the right div using the `.collapse` class (some were missing the class). I changed it to find the div whose id begins with "long".

Comment: didn't help either, I've thought the same first, so I've added `.more` class but it rested same.

Comment: try this `$(item).find("div[id^='long']").removeClass('in').addClass('collapse');`